# OpenCV detect face landmarks (ear-chin-ear line)

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I am looking to an opencv function (in python) detecting the line left ear - chin - right ear (that looks like a parabol) on human faces. Is there any kind of haarcascade doing this job? I already know the frontal face or the eyes haarcascades but I am looking for something more precise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you are looking for is called face landmark detection . You can try DLIB . DLIB is written in C++ but it also have a python wrapper .[Install Instructions](http://dlib.net/compile.html)

Now using DLib you can achieve this

## Code

```
import cv2
import dlib
import numpy

PREDICTOR_PATH = "/home/zed/dlib/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)
cascade_path='haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)

# #This is using the Dlib Face Detector . Better result more time taking
# def get_landmarks(im):
#     rects = detector(im, 1)
#     rect=rects[0]
#     print type(rect.width())
#     fwd=int(rect.width())
#     if len(rects) == 0:
#         return None,None

#     return np.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(im, rects[0]).parts()]),fwd

def get_landmarks(im):
    rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(im, 1.3,5)
    x,y,w,h =rects[0]
    rect=dlib.rectangle(x,y,x+w,y+h)
    return numpy.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(im, rect).parts()])

def annotate_landmarks(im, landmarks):
    im = im.copy()
    for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks):
        pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
        cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,
                    fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,
                    fontScale=0.4,
                    color=(0, 0, 255))
        cv2.circle(im, pos, 3, color=(0, 255, 255))
    return im

im=cv2.imread('face_leo1.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Result',annotate_landmarks(im,get_landmarks(im)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Results

[image]

## Points related to landmark :

```
FACE_POINTS = list(range(17, 68))
MOUTH_POINTS = list(range(48, 61))
RIGHT_BROW_POINTS = list(range(17, 22))
LEFT_BROW_POINTS = list(range(22, 27))
RIGHT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(36, 42))
LEFT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(42, 48))
NOSE_POINTS = list(range(27, 35))
JAW_POINTS = list(range(0, 17))
CHIN_POINTS=list(range(6,11))
```

Comment: Nevertheless I get an error at the line `rect=dlib.rectangle(x,y,x+w,y+h)` which is `Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    rectangle.__init__(rectangle, numpy.int32, numpy.int32, numpy.int32, numpy.int32)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(_object*, long left, long top, long right, long bottom)
    __init__(_object*)
`
Did you already get this error and know how to fix it?

Comment: I didn't got any error exactly like this but I faced a lot of issues and came up with this solution and it worked.  :/ you have the correct path to cascade ?? and the predictor ??

Comment: I solved the problem by writing `x,y,w,h =rects[0].astype(long)`

Comment: It works now? I added another method that uses the dlib facedetector instead of the Opencv haar cascade one

Comment: yes it works. Apparently the cascade gave `int32` rectangles whereas the dlib rectangle method (which is written in C++) expect `long` integers

Answer (score 0):

There is also an easy-to-use wrapper for [dlib](http://dlib.net/) called [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition).

```py
from face_recognition import load_image_file, face_locations

# load to numpy array
img_array = load_image_file("img.jpg")

# returns a list with a dict for each face
# each face-dict contains landmarks for features like chin, nose.. etc
landmarks = face_locations(img_array)
```

[image: img from thispersondoesnotexist.com]