# OpenCV and dlib Face detection

Tags: anaconda, python-3.5, opencv3.0, face-detection, dlib

I am using the code mentioned in the link :

[OpenCV detect face landmarks (ear-chin-ear line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210655/opencv-detect-face-landmarks-ear-chin-ear-line)

I executed it on Anaconda Python3.5 using opencv3 and dlib but I get the following error :

```
rect=dlib.rectangle(x,y,x+w,y+h) which is Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in rectangle.__init__(rectangle, numpy.int32, numpy.int32, numpy.int32, numpy.int32) did not match C++ signature: __init__(_object*, long left, long top, long right, long bottom) __init__(_object*)
```

I changed the type of the parameters using :

```
x,y,w,h =rects[0].astype('long')
```

But the same error persists. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Dlib comes with complete example programs that show how to do this.  You should refer to that code since it's correct: http://dlib.net/face_recognition.py.html

Also, here are other python example programs.  They all run correctly: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/tree/master/python_examples

Comment: The code I am  referring to is one of the mostly used codes and the error that I am getting is that dlib requires argument of long type so even after type casting I am getting the same error. So I just wished to debug it.Maybe if you can help.

Comment: How can it be 'the mostly used code' if it doesn't even work?

Comment: But there must be some way out to make that code work...Just curious to solve for Python 3 and dlib.

Comment: Dlib works fine with python3.  Your code is just wrong.  There is literally working python code on the dlib website that does this, which is in my answer.  Use it.